# CSV - How to add columns based on an existing column?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

What is the best way to do this and how?

I gather things called `sed`, `AWK` and `bash` may be relevant.
I have used `AWK` once for one command, the others never.
I have searched and other apparently similar questions do not have an answer I need.

I have columns I have called `fields` in a CSV file:

```
_________________________
field1 | field2 | field3|
-------------------------
1990AB | 123456 | 123456|
-------------------------
```

I want to add `fields` based on these three original `fields` to appear as follows:

```
_______________________________________________________
field1 | field2 | field3 | field1a | field2a | field3a |
-------------------------------------------------------
1990AB | 123456 | 123456|  1990   |  12345  |  12345  |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

where:

- `field1a` 1990  column 1 first 4 always digits then alpha
- `field2a` 12345 column 2 is always 6 digits
- `field3a` 12345 column 3 is always 6 digits

These are one-time-per-file actions, prior to database import.

`macosx` has about 6 million records. 2nd attempt at this question as my first was apparently not good. In this area I am a 100% novice.

Comment: Is your file schema pipe delimited with space between the data just like this? Is there an extra record between your header and your data that is full of dashes? If not can you share exactly what your file looks like (first few records) and exactly what your desired output is?

Comment: Also, for your desired output, is it that you just want the first 4 characters of `field`, the first 5 characters of `field2` and `field3` to appear as new fields in your record? Or is there some other logic applied here, like `field4` is just the numeric portions of `field1`, and `field5` and `field6` are `field2` and `field3` divided by 10 and rounded down to the nearest integer.

Comment: The pipe spaces and underscores and dashes are meant to be artwork for stackoverflow's preferred presentation I was led to believe I should use if I desire answers. This is a comma-delimited file, so field1,field2,fieldn,.. and yes there is a header row1. I am assuming "file schema" means how it is laid out. I'll edit the question a bit to answer your other questions. Thanks.

Comment: The "preferred" layout is totally dependent on the question. If this was a question for Excel or a Database then the schema/layout doesn't matter and prettying it up will help make it legible. But since your file schema is important for answering it would help here.

Comment: Get rid of the artwork and show us your real data. We need you to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output that we can test a potential solution against, not a representation we can just look at and try to guess at what your real data is that might produce that view (quoted fields? spaces around fields? etc.).

Comment: @EdMorton This should be bold: **We need you to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output that we can test a potential solution against** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

this should be easy to read even if you have no prior experience with `awk`

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=3;i++) $(++NF)=$i"a"}    
                    NR>1  {$(++NF)=substr($1,1,4); 
                           $(++NF)=substr($2,1,5);
                           $(++NF)=substr($3,1,5)}1' file
```

`NR` is line number, special treatment for header, `NF` is number of fields, here incrementing for each additional column and `$i` is field value at position `i`.  The last `1` is shorthand for printing the line.  Initial options are for setting input field delimiter (F) and output field delimiter (OFS) to comma.

Comment: That will completely corrupt the output given some CSV input files, and add fields of just 0 for others, and have other side-effects for yet others. Not sure it's worth posting an answer until we see what the input looks like since half the time when people say their input is CSV there isn't a comma in sight, it's tab or semi-colon or something else separated, and we have no idea if the fields are within quotes, or can contain commas, or even can cross lines, etc. For anyone else reading this, don't assume if this works for one CSV format it'll work for your specific format.

Comment: Says here -v sets a (one) variable but I can't see you setting one, how's that work? and you have ++ to increment this mysterious variable?

Comment: variable set is output field separator, implied in the print statement (here `1`).  `NF` is the number of fields, each time we're adding a new column, it's incremented and the new field is set. Is the explanation in the answer not clear enough?